# Allrunes overleaf

Tags: fonts, overleaf

I want to use runes in my LaTex document, and I have found the allrunes package. But it seems it can only be installed on my PC, and I can't see how I can implement it in Overleaf.

How should this be done?

Comment: it's in texlive so I'd expect it to be available in overleaf by default. what error did you get?

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) I see David's already beat me to the punch, but his answer is correct (of course it is :-). If you still run into problems, there might be something to do with your project that's preventing this from working. In that case, please write us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, and we can take a closer look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is in texlive and so overleaf so you don't need to do anything special, this just tries an example from the package manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{allrunes}

\begin{document}

zz \textarc{Aabcdefg} zzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I'm afraid I had put the usepackage in the wrong document, so that's why it didn't work.